# Running cmake 'make' in command does not work

Tags: c++, c, cmd, compilation, cmake

I'm trying to build a version of code I got from github ([link](https://github.com/nclack/whisk#building)) according to the instructions there. 
I ran the following:

```
mkdir build
 cd build
 cmake ..
```

which seems to work fine. However, when I get to the last bit and try to run:

```
make
```

I'm getting a message that it is not recognized. 
I have installed and double checked the paths of bison, gawk and cmake, and they all seem to be included in the system PATH.
Does anyone have any suggestion what might be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to install make? (cmake and make are different programs, with distinct vendors)

Comment: No. I wasn't aware it's a different thing than cmake. I will look into that.

Comment: It depends on your plataform, but you can start looking at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/

Comment: Since this was tagged with `cmd`, is this windows? Do you have mingw installed or what compiler are you using?

Comment: What OS you are on? What compiler are you trying to use?

Comment: Yes this is indeed windows (7, if it matters). I am not sure about which compiler I am using - I have bison and gawk installed. And now also make installed

Comment: After installing make, I'm getting the follwoing error:
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: ***I am not sure about which compiler I am using*** That is something you have to know. If you did not install a compiler you can't build anything... Windows does not ship with any compiler.

Comment: Ok it's gcc sorry

Comment: "`make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.`" it seems to me that cmake was not ran successfully

Comment: Did you try `cmake -G  "MinGW Makefiles" ..` Like in this example: https://github.com/tudelft3d/masbcpp/wiki/Building-on-Windows-with-CMake-and-MinGW

Comment: @drescherjm I get a bunch of errors (below). I'm guessing I have a compiler problem?

`CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage`

Comment: It seems mingw is not installed or not in your path. When you said you have `gcc` on windows that is still somewhat unclear. `gcc` can be installed several different ways under windows. `cygwin` is one other way and the cmake instructions would be different for that.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the command `make` only works when there is a file named "makefile" in the current directory. Using `makefile -f "filename"` will let make know the file is a makefile, and treat it as such. Or you can change the makefile name to "makefile".